# Automate 2 scripts interacting with each others using expect

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I have 2 simple scripts that I need them to automatically interact with each others using a third `expect` script

`script1.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "s1: started"
echo "question1"
read
echo "got ${REPLY}"
echo "question2"
read
echo "got ${REPLY}"
echo "question3"
read
echo "got ${REPLY}"
echo "s1: finished"
```

`script2.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "s2: started"
read
echo "got ${REPLY}"
echo "answer1"
read
echo "got ${REPLY}"
echo "answer2"
read
echo "got ${REPLY}"
echo "answer3"
echo "s2: finished"
```

`auto_s1_s2.exp`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn -noecho ./script1.sh
set s1ID $spawn_id

spawn -noecho ./script2.sh
set s2ID $spawn_id

expect -i $s1ID "question1" {
    send_user "exp: question1\n"
    send -i $s2ID "question1\r"
    expect -i $s2ID "answer1" {
        send_user "exp: answer1\n"
        send -i $s1ID "answer1\r"
    }
}
interact
```

The output of running `./auto_s1_s2.exp` however is:

```
s1: started
question1
exp: question1
question1
s2: started
got question1
answer1
exp: answer1
```

I am expecting that `s1` echoes `question1` which is verify against `expect $s1ID "question1"` then the expect script would send `question1` to `s2` and expects `answer1` from it then it sends `answer` to `s1` and so on

[image: Illustration here]

It seems that `answer1` was not received by `script1`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: others cannot guess what you're going to do from your script since it did not work as you expected. could you elaborate what's your purpose?

Comment: @pynexj I added more information

Comment: `script1` does get the `answer1`, but your interact command will not show it. You need to tell it to listen to the spawn id: `interact -i $s1ID `

Comment: There's an example program in the Expect source that demonstrates two chess programs playing each other: https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/artifact/57b2967d35be0a0d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full example.

#### Shell part:

```
[STEP 101] $ cat s1.sh
echo "s1: started"
echo "question1"
read
echo "got ${REPLY}"
echo "question2"
read
echo "got ${REPLY}"
echo "question3"
read
echo "got ${REPLY}"
echo "s1: finished"
[STEP 102] $ cat s2.sh
echo "s2: started"
read
echo "got ${REPLY}"
echo "answer1"
read
echo "got ${REPLY}"
echo "answer2"
read
echo "got ${REPLY}"
echo "answer3"
echo "s2: finished"
[STEP 103] $
```

#### Expect part:

```
[STEP 104] $ cat qa.exp
spawn bash s1.sh
set s1 $spawn_id

spawn bash s2.sh
set s2 $spawn_id

expect -i $s1 "s1: started"
expect -i $s2 "s2: started"

expect {
    -i $s1 -re "(question.)" {
        set q $expect_out(1,string)

        send -i $s2 "$q\r"
        expect -i $s2 -re "got\[^\r\n]+\[\r\n]+"
        expect -i $s2 -re "(\[^\r\n]+)\[\r\n]+$"
        set a $expect_out(1,string)

        send -i $s1 "$a\r"

        exp_continue
    }
    -i $s1 eof {
        exp_continue
    }
    -i $s2 eof {
    }
}
```

#### Result:

```
[STEP 105] $ expect qa.exp
spawn bash s1.sh
spawn bash s2.sh
s1: started
question1
s2: started
question1
got question1
answer1
answer1
got answer1
question2
question2
got question2
answer2
answer2
got answer2
question3
question3
got question3
answer3
s2: finished
s2: finished
got s2: finished
s1: finished
[STEP 106] $
```

Comment: your answer yields the correct result, but I couldn't understand the regular expression's behavior here

Comment: `expect -d qa.exp` can give you detailed info.

Answer (score 1):

Give you an example with [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/):

```
[bash] # cat qa.sh
sock1=/tmp/s1.$$.sock
sock2=/tmp/s2.$$.sock

sexpect -s $sock1 spawn bash s1.sh
sexpect -s $sock1 expect 's1: started'

sexpect -s $sock2 spawn bash s2.sh
sexpect -s $sock2 expect 's2: started'

while true; do
    sexpect -s $sock1 expect -re '(question.)'
    ret=$?
    if sexpect chkerr -err $ret -is eof; then
        break
    fi
    q=$( sexpect -s $sock1 expect_out -i 1 )

    sexpect -s $sock2 send -cr "$q"
    sexpect -s $sock2 expect -re $'got[^\r\n]+[\r\n]+'
    sexpect -s $sock2 expect -re $'([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]+$'
    a=$( sexpect -s $sock2 expect_out -i 1 )

    sexpect -s $sock1 send -cr "$a"
done

sexpect -s $sock1 wait
sexpect -s $sock2 wait
[bash] #
```

Result:

```
[bash] # bash qa.sh
s1: started
s2: started
question1
question1
got question1
answer1
answer1
got answer1
question2
question2
got question2
answer2
answer2
got answer2
question3
question3
got question3
answer3
s2: finished
s2: finished
got s2: finished
s1: finished
[bash] #
```

Answer (score 0):

As [meuh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5008284/meuh) mentioned [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771885/automate-2-scripts-interacting-with-each-others-using-expect#comment116290145_65771885), the expect script is working fine but not showing the output due to the interact not listening to a certain spawn_id