# Bash: Mutual interaction of processes via pipes

Tags: bash, pipe, coproc

**ENVIRONMENT:** Linux/Docker, bash version 4.2.

**QUESTION:**

- `server-app` accepts commands with an interactive shell.
- `server-app` receives commands originating from a `client.sh` through a pipe.
- `server-app` writes to the standard output received by `client.sh`.
- `client.sh` considers `server-app`'s output to determine further commands.
- `server-app` might also ask for a password => That is, the terminal's standard input must be forwarded to `server-app` along with the output of `client.sh`.

I tried multiple setups with `coproc`. However, I either run into a stalled situation or
data has not been received. How can such a setup as, shown below, be implemented in `bash`?

```
                       .------>------------------------.
     .---------.       |         .------------.  stdin |       .-----------.
     | user    |-------'         | server-app |<-------+-------| client.sh |
     | console |<--+-------------|            |     .--------->|           |
     '---------'   |      stdout '------------'     |          '-----------'
                   '--------------------------------'
```

**MY TRY:**

```
coproc server.app

function expect { local expectation=$1
        # read from pipe until $expectation occurs in the input stream
        # when found, echo the line to 'stdout'
        echo "EXPECT: '$expectation'"
        while true; do
            read text <&"${COPROC[0]}"
            if [[ "$text" == *"$expectation"* ]]; then
                    echo $text 
                    break
            fi
        done
}

function send { local command=$1
        # send $command through pipe 
        echo "SEND: $command"
        echo "$command" >&"${COPROC[1]}"

}


expect "Conected to URL" 
send   "open"
expect "Session keepalive"
send   "session open"

# use the reported session identifier to setup the user command
session_n=$(expect "Identifier of Session created" | cut -d' ' -f5)    
command=$(echo "$user_command" | sed -e "s/SESSION/$session_n/g")
```

The last three lines only demonstrate a possible processing of the `server-app`'s
output. Again what is wrong with that? How can it be brought to work.

Comment: bash's `coproc` is quite buggy: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-04/msg00014.html

Comment: That might be an explanation. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: Does "terminal" represent some process or it's meant to be parent stdin/stdout? Reading input from multiple places makes little sense - what do you expect to happen when input interleave? Should the input to `server-app` come from terminal or from client.sh?

Comment: you can use [tag:expect] or similar tools. take a look at my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) if you prefer using shell.

Comment: Well, is `user console` some program, or it's meant to represent parent stdin/stdout?

Comment: note that its not easy to feed password to a prog unless it supports getting passwd in an insecure way.

Comment: @ Expect for Shells: Would you, please, pinpoint a solution and post it as an answer?

Comment: user console provides the parent stdin/stdout.

Comment: Sure. So what should happen with that input interleaving? Imagine I type `something\n` and then __at the same time__ client.sh outputs `else\n`? Should the input be `soelthing\nse\n`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771885/ has examples for both expect and sexpect.

Comment: @KamiCuk, of course not. The user would see 'please, provide password' and ``client.sh`` keeps silent meanwhile.

Comment: Oooch, so it's not stdin connected to `server-app`, but there is a program between, right? And that program, receives lines from `server-app` and makes decisions where from to read next?

Comment: Not necessarily, if the ``client.sh`` sees ``password``it stays calm, while the user feeds its password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As metioned by @sexpect the 'natural' way is to solve the problem is *expect*. This tool takes a Tcl-based script as input.

```
 spawn server-app
```

would start the `server-app` under control of expect. `expect` is also a keyword in these scritps.

```
 expect -re "something (..)"
```

waits for output matching the expression `something (..)`.

```
 send ...
```

sends some characters to the application.

```
expect_tty ...
```

takes some input from the user that launched the expect script.